# How to get name of id attribute with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want html code like here:

```
<div class='form' id='srow1'>
<div class='form' id='srow2'>
<div class='form' id='srow3'>
```

How to get name of id with JavaScript?

Comment: Try `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.form')).map(x => x.getAttribute('id'))`

Answer (score 0):

Select the elements using some other CSS selector and then access the id property. You could also use the getAttribute("id") method.

```js
var $divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");

for(var i = 0; i < $divs.length; i++){

     console.log($divs[i].id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById()`.

Read the documentation. At least here: https://developer.mozilla.org

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

```js
const idList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.form')).map((element) => element.getAttribute('id'));

console.log(idList);
```

```html
<div class='form' id='srow1'></div>
<div class='form' id='srow2'></div>
<div class='form' id='srow3'></div>
```